# Why my Firebase firestore data is not showing in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an application where anyone can list their products. I am storing data in Firebase Firestore in nested collection Now I want to retrieve that data and show that on my home screen. Now the data is showing but the problem is that it is showing only when I am login in with that same number through that I list that data into Firebase but when I try to log in with another number the data doesn't show. I want that to show to everyone who logged in to the app. Basically My app is just like OLX where anyone can list anything which shows to everyone.

**MY CODE TO RETRIEVE THE DATA**

```
  //CODE TO GET CURRENT ID OR USER
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    //CODE TO GET THE DATA FROM FIREBASE

    DocumentReference uidRef =  firebaseFirestore.collection("listing_details").document(uid);
    CollectionReference roomDetailsRef = uidRef.collection("room_details");
    String doc_id = roomDetailsRef.document().getId();

    
    roomDetailsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    if (document != null) {
                        RoomsDetails obj = document.toObject(RoomsDetails.class);
                        roomsDetails.add(obj);
                    }
                }
                roomsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have `.document(uid)` in your path where UID is User ID of user currently logged in. When you use another phone number, that's a different user. So documents under `/listing_details/user_1` will not show up with another user as you are querying `listing_details/user_2`. What's the use case? Can you share a screenshot of your database and explain what documents can be queried by any users in your app?

Comment: yes brother I am working on an app like OLX where anyone can list their items now. Suppose that if 4 users listed their items and fifth one log in then the data of the all 4 users should be shown to that user.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your database structure including root and sub collections and then explain which document are you trying to query. From my understanding so far you need all documents under `room_details` of all documents in `listing_details`.

Comment: yes brother i am adding

Comment: Have you tried [Collection Group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#java_30) queries? That should return all "room_details" documents. Try the query as in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/eef38e1dcc9d54cb8e537357621258a6).

Comment: will it  return for all of the users brother

Comment: Yes, essentially `collectionGroup()` will return docs from all collections with that name. Best to try out :)

Comment: Dharmaraj brother thanks a lot, thanks a lot i was trying to figure it out since morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `.document(uid)` in your path where UID is User ID of user currently logged in. When you use another phone number, that's a different user.

If you want to fetch `room_details` documents from all `listing_details` documents then you can use [Collection Group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#java_30) queries like this:

```
db.collectionGroup("room_details").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                // ... iterate over all docs and render
            }
        });
```